# Concise Dynamic List of Key Value Pairs

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# app. In that app, I have a need to pass an arbitrary list of key value pairs. I want to pass those key/values to a utility method that looks something like this:

```
public void PrettyPrint(string message, [type?] kvp)
{
  Console.WriteLine(message);
  foreach (var p in kvp)
  {
    Console.Write(p.Key + "\t\t\t" + p.Value);
  }
}
```

Please note, that's just pseduocode. I then want to call this function using something like this:

```
PrettyPrint("Results:", { quantity:4, total:"$1.23", tax:"0.10" });
```

Everything I see using C# seems bulky for just passing key value pairs. Am I overrlooking something? Is there a concise way of just passing a dynamic list of key value pairs in C#

Comment: You could create a data class, or just a datatable and populate those with your key/value pairs and pass that

Comment: You can pass `Dictionary<string,decimal>` and work with it

Comment: I hear key value pairs, I think Dictionary that's what it's made for.

Comment: You could just `public void PrettyPrint(string message, params object[] kvp)` where every 2nd is the value - so [0] = key, [1] = value, [3] = key, [4] = value .... is the "shortest" form to write it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just use C# 7's [value tuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) and the `params` keyword:

```
public static void PrettyPrint(string message, params (object key, object value)[] kvp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    foreach (var p in kvp)
    {
        Console.Write(p.key + "\t\t\t" + p.value);
    }
}
```

Called like this:

```
PrettyPrint("Results: ", ("quantity", 4), ("total", "$1.23"), ("tax", 0.10));
```

Or, storing the pairs in a variable:

```
(object, object)[] pairs = {("quantity", 4), ("total", "$1.23"), ("tax", 0.10)};
PrettyPrint("Results: ", pairs);
```

*or slightly more concisely using the loop like `foreach (var (key, value) in kvp)` to avoid the `p` and the item names in the method signature*

```
public static void PrettyPrint(string message, params (object, object)[] kvp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    foreach (var (key, value) in kvp)
    {
        Console.Write($"{key}\t\t\t{value}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest (by syntax) to what you need I think can be achieved by accepting plain `object` and reflect over its properties:

```
public static void PrettyPrint(string message, object kvp) {
    if (kvp == null)
        return;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    foreach (var p in kvp.GetType().GetProperties()) {
        Console.Write(p.Name + "\t\t\t" + p.GetValue(kvp));
    }
}
```

That is because then you can pass anonymous objects there:

```
PrettyPrint("Results:", new { quantity = 4, total = "$1.23", tax = "0.10" });
```

That's basically the same as you would do that in javascipt (which syntax you used for an example of what you want).

Comment: You could create a little extension method for object here to make it look a little nearer the original: `obj.GetType().GetProperties().Select(o => new KeyValuePair<object, object>(o.Name, o.GetValue(obj)));`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Dictionary` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) or a `List<Tuple<string,float>>` for example

```
PrettyPrint("Results:", new Dictionary<string, float>() 
{
   { "quantity",4 }, 
   { "total", 1.23 }
});
```

Comment: The problem with a `Dictionary` is defining the key value pairs to pass to the method. Just seems bulky unless there's a concise way I'm not seeing.

Comment: @user687554: SInce your example only uses the values as strings, you could generalize this to a `Dictionary<string, object>` to accomodate all types. Note that you can't do anything type specific with the values then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, for example, Json.Net. This way you can submit absolutely any object.

```
public void PrettyPrint(string message, object kvp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kvp, Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

The result is quite pretty.